# Convert raw string that contain "Array" to PHP Array or JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I have string that look like `Array` that fetched from other webservice like this

```
[
    [
        [189, 'Brazil Serie A', 0, ''],
        [
            [1053230, 'Flamengo', 'Atletico Goianiense', '1.196', 10, '07/02/2012 04:30', 0, 9, 1, 0, '', 0]
        ],
        [0, [
            [10770901, 0, 5000.00],
            [1, 17988654, '-0.78', '0.70', '1.0', 1],
            [3, 17965783, '0.97', '0.93', '2.5-3'],
            [7, 17965787, '-0.89', '0.77', '0.50', 1],
            [9, 17965789, '0.70', '-0.82', '1.0']
        ]]
    ],
    [, , [0, [
        [10748028, 0, 3000.00],
        [1, 17965781, '0.85', '-0.93', '0.5-1', 1],
        [3, 17988655, '0.79', '-0.89', '2.50']
    ]]]
]
```

Is it possible to parsing to `PHP Array` or convert to `JSON` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ctrahey noted, the single quotes need to be swapped to double quotes to be valid JSON. The commas without anything preceding them also have to go.

```php
// quote to double quote                
$input = str_replace("'", '"', $input);                 

// remove empty commas
$input = preg_replace('/,\s*,/', ',', $input);          
$input = preg_replace('/\[\s*,/', '[', $input);

$output = json_decode($input));
```

I've tried to keep it simple and build a little flexibility in.

Answer (score 1):

Um, at first glance... if you convert your single quotes to double quotes, you already have JSON. I switched about half and it was validating okay through that point.

See [the spec](http://www.json.org/) for details, but this is essentially just a bunch of arrays. The double-quote requirement for strings is clearly stated there, and the rest looks okay.

Comment: empty commas in the final block also appear to be an issue

Comment: Good catch, @JohnC. A cleanup routine would need replace them with null, perhaps matching either `[,` and replacing it with `[null,` or `,,` with `,null,` (as a suggestion to @meddlesome

Comment: Thanks to point out in problems for parsing original data, It's working now ! John C and ctrahey